# asyncio.gather() is starting first two tasks but not the third one

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio, python-3.6

I have a python function that is supposed to send packet asynchronously in a loop.

```
import asyncio
import logging
import pickle
from time import sleep

from decoder import decode, encode
from socket import *

UDP_PORT_NUMBER = 44006
HOST_ADDRESS = "192.168.204.139"
server_address = (HOST_ADDRESS, UDP_PORT_NUMBER)


def get_data_packet():
    with open('../packets/packet_15', mode='rb') as fpt:
        packet = pickle.load(fpt, encoding='bytes')        
    return packet   
    

class GcuUdpClient:

    @staticmethod
    async def send_packets():
        data = get_data_packet()
        client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
        client_socket.sendto(data, server_address)
        print('sending data packets')
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
```

I have another python program that calls this class, along with two other classes.

```
import asyncio
from http_server import PostServer
from grpc_server import GrpcServer
from gcu_udp_client import GcuUdpClient


async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(GrpcServer.run(), PostServer.run_server(), GcuUdpClient.send_packets())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

This code starts up the first two meaning
`GrpcServer.run()`
and
`PostServer.run_server()`

However I can't get the last one started, to send out the packets. What am I missing.

Adding the code for http_server.py

```
import threading
import zlib
from http import HTTPStatus
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from io import BytesIO
from socket import *
from time import sleep
#from GCUSimulator.generated.GDataPayload_pb2 import GDataPayload
from generated.GDataPayload_pb2 import GDataPayload

HTTP_PORT_NUMBER = 8085
HTTP_SERVER_IP="192.168.204.1"


class SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.subscribed = False
        super(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, *kwargs)

    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()

    def do_POST(self):
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])  # <--- Gets the size of data
        post_data = self.rfile.read(content_length)  # <--- Gets the data itself
        print("POST Path: {0} Headers: {1} Body: {2}".
              format(str(self.path),  str(self.headers), post_data.decode('utf-8')))
        if str(self.path) == '/setSubscriber.php':
            message = "Subscription Result:Subscribed,APIVersion:1.0.0"
            self.send_response(HTTPStatus.OK)
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(message.encode('utf-8'))
            self.subscribed = True

        elif str(self.path) == '/removeSubscriber.php':
            self.send_response(HTTPStatus.OK)
            self.end_headers()
            self.subscribed = False

    def get_subscription_status(self):
        return self.subscribed


class PostServer:

    @staticmethod
    async def run_server(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=SimpleHTTPRequestHandler, addr=HTTP_SERVER_IP, port=HTTP_PORT_NUMBER):

        server_address = (addr, port)
        print('Http Post server : {0}:{1}'.format(addr, port))
        httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
        await httpd.serve_forever()
```

Adding the code for grpc_server.py

```
from concurrent import futures
import grpc
from generated import guidance_grpc_service_definitions_pb2_grpc
from gcu.ops_station_services import OPSStationServices

GRPC_PORT_NUMBER = 12074


class GrpcServer:

    @staticmethod
    async def run():
        server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))
        guidance_grpc_service_definitions_pb2_grpc.add_OpRPCServicesServicer_to_server(OServices(), server)
        server.add_insecure_port('[::]:{0}'.format(GRPC_PORT_NUMBER))
        print('Grpc Server : {0}:{1}'.format('localhost', GRPC_PORT_NUMBER))
        server.start()
#        server.wait_for_termination()
```

Comment: Is it possible that either of the first two functions block (eg, on a network connection or read)?  That will stall the event loop, preventing any other async functions from running.  The one function you do include the source for does disk and network I/O in a potentially blocking manner - it's best practice to make all I/O fully async to avoid the risk of stalling the event loop.

Comment: @craigb - I have added the code for http_server.py and grpc_server.py. Can you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: `GrpcServer` looks ok - it should be non-blocking (provided you don't call `server.wait_for_termination()`).  I don't see the code for `PostServer()`. If you remove that, does the 3rd function run ok? Since asyncio by default uses a single event loop (meaning there's really just one execution thread), your code must not block.  So network I/O has to be non-blocking, which is typically done with [`asyncio streams`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html).

Comment: @craigb - there was a typo. Have update the PostServer() code

Comment: Also - If I add only ` await asyncio.gather(GrpcServer.run(), PostServer.run_server())` then it works fine. So I think problem is in `GcuUdpClient.send_packets()`

Comment: Yes, it's good to bisect to debug.  You can also add `await asyncio.sleep(5)` in the suspect function, moving it down after each statement.  That will give 5 seconds for the other functions to run.  I am confused by `PostServer.run_server()` though.  It seems to call `await http.server.HTTPServer()` which is not an async function.  That should give an error.